# Simple email list manager

Tags: open-source, web-apps, php, self-hosted, mailing-list

I'm looking for a simple email list server that I can install on my organization's web server.

I'm the webmaster for a small charitable organization with about 600 regular donors and one or two major events each year; currently our Corresponding Secretary manages donor communications manually using Thunderbird and Quattro Pro. I'd like to automate this, as well as facilitate communication between the Directors of the organization.

I need the following capabilities:

- Manage two or three separate lists of recipients
- Manual approval of outgoing mailings
- Double-opt-in subscribe
- Double-opt-out unsubscribe
- Should encrypt subscriber addresses, although I can hack this in myself if needed

In addition it has to run on our server, under PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.something.

Comment: I suggest you look into MailChimp (free version) with up to 2,000 subscribers.  We use this setup and it meets most of your concerns.(except it is NOT installed on your server). Less setup and maintenance and runs in conjunction with or independently from your website.

Comment: @KevanSheridan MailChimp is certainly an option, although I was kinda hoping for something I could tear apart to see how it works. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking this, I have discovered that my hosting provider includes [MailMan](https://wiki.list.org/) in my hosting package; this has proved perfect for communication among the Executive and the Members.

For Donor communication, I have gone with [phpList](https://www.phplist.org/) which offers a central subscriber database with separate subscription lists, bounce management, subscriber import/export as .csv file, and it is Open Source and runs on our server. For those who need it, they also offer a managed service option akin to MailChimp.